# python dataframe column search latin

Tags: python, dataframe, iso-8859-1

I have 5 different dataframes. Their columns and column types are all different. These dfs are created from excels. I have a script that reads through the df's and pushes it to MySQL. 
Some of the excels have latin characters. I want to set sys.setdefaultencoding('latin-1') if they contain latin characters anywhere within the df. 
This is what I have and it doesn't work. How do I fix this?

This is my Error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
                for column in df:
                  if df[column].astype(str).str.contains(ur'[^\x00-\x7F\x80-\xFF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-\u024F\u1E00-\u1EFF]'):
                    sys.setdefaultencoding('latin-1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called a function, `contains`, on an entire column.  The result is a column-sized array of Boolean values.  `if` requires a Boolean expression.

I expect that you need to add the `any` reduction operator to your expression.

```
if any(df[column] ... ):
    sys.setdefaultencoding('latin-1')
```